# rootScope is not working to bind data from controller to view

Tags: angularjs

i m new in angularjs. But there is problem that i cant resolve it my code is below

My index.html file is given below

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app = "myApp">
     <head>
          <script src=""https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js""></script>
          <script>
               var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
               app.run(function($rootScope){
               $rootScope.name = "Ari Lerner";
               });
         </script>
     </head>
     <body>
            <div>
               {{name}}
            </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

But still the output on Browser in
     {{name}}
  please help to solve my problem

Comment: I think that you need controller.

Answer (score 3):

I think you made this pretty complex for your self. You need to play with the scope of that moment instead of using the rootScope when their is only one level of scope involved.

However in order to make your example work created a fiddle for the same:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DtZk6/2/)

Code Snippet:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="test">
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function test($scope){
   $scope.name = "Ari Lerner";
}
```

Comment: @shailesh: is this problem of yours is solved? If yes do mark it as your answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your angularjs is included properly:

Put double quotes only once:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKzqD/)